# Android expandablelistview child click listener not working

Tags: android

in my android project i am using `Expandablelistview` with `SimpleExpandableListAdapter`,its `onGroupexpand` function is working but `onChildClick` function whick is under `setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() )` is not working.
I have read all the stackoverflow articles regarding this ,but its not working.What could be possible error....

Comment: Can you post your code..

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise go for LayoutInflater concept. Maybe your problem may solve.

Comment: When i am using a default layout for child,its child click listener is working,but when i am using custom layout for child elements,its listener is not working...may be i am missing something in case of child listener.

Comment: What i am understanding is that,in baseexpandable list adapter in getChildview method it returns a view,but my child is combination of diffrent view like textviews,images,and other,so this is a Viewgroup,so wt to do to eliminate this problem...

Comment: use ListAdapter adapter=new ListAdapter();
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{  
@Override
public int getCount() {     
return position ;
}@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {   
return position;
}@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.urcustomlayout, parent, false);TextView tt=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textviewid);

Comment: same like remaining views & ids
these view functionalities here like if u have button
button.setonclicklistener()...etc }}